# What kind of framing is this and how to frame for wall hung toilet

Tags: walls, framing, toilet

My summer project is to remodel my master bathroom. When I open the wall and saw its not a tranditional 2x4 stud, I would like to know the name of the framing so that I can research a bit about how to add wall hung framing into it. As you can see from the photo, **6-3/4 inches** for the wall and made of studs. The other side of the room is guest bathroom. There are vent and HVAC inside this wall.

To me, they looks like 2 separate rooms and connected together using a horizontal stud.

I am following my wall hung toilet's manual but this framing does not seem to be a typical framing and i couldn't find example online. Can you help me identify this type of framing? How should I frame for my wall hung toilet in this type of wall?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is most likely a wall for reducing sound transmission.

Comment: I take it you're the sole owner of the structure in question?

Comment: It's the kind of framing that looks like it's the basis for some Scooby Do-style secret passages between rooms, except that nobody but a mouse could fit through that extra 3" of space.

Comment: On a more serious note, I was going to suggest that the horizontal 2x4 banding was to support the edges of drywall installed horizontally instead of vertically, but there's a vertical edge visible in one of the pics, so that's right out. Unless someone has a legitimate reason for this, I'd suggest removing the banding on the bathroom side and enlarge your bathroom by that 1.5". Doesn't sound like much, but every inch helps. Especially if you discover this on all 4 walls, that gives you an extra 3" in each dimension.

Comment: There's a 4" stack in there which requires 6" of space because that's the size of the bell on cast iron? - I'd call it sideways and furred. And needs to be VIF (verify in field) because the plans just show a pipe in a 2x4 wall and that's not going to fit it. It's called *ah-hoc*, aka, *some BS you gotta deal with* because you're trying to hang something that belongs bolted to a toilet flange. - I'd've done a bunch of swearing before even starting. Finding that, I'd have to ask you if you want me to gut the whole thing, or just not have a nifty pita-to-install toilet.

Comment: *How should I frame for my wall hung toilet* - model number; instructions? - If it isn't balloon framing, or e.g., [16"]oc, then I'm out of names for it. It is... *"what they did"*.